# Android NDK write to SQLite

Tags: java, android, c++, sqlite, android-ndk

in my work I am trying to do some comparisons and as such I need to be able to write to database from NDK.
I tried to inspire from [this source](http://blog.kdehairy.com/using-sqlite-natively-on-android/), but I keep getting (from emulator and physical device) following error on insert:
**file is encrypted or is not a database**

*My relevant piece of code:*

```
extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_package_Benchmark_getMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jstring filePath, jstring databasePath)
    {
        sqlite3 *db;
        const char *database = env->GetStringUTFChars(databasePath, 0);
        if (sqlite3_open_v2(database, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) // returns zero but probably sets db as read-only
        {
            if (SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO lessons (wordCount, wordPassedCount, lessonName, selected) VALUES (0, 0, '50k', 0)", NULL, NULL, NULL))
                LOGD("%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db)); // here i get the error
            int lesson_id = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
            return env->NewStringUTF("Database opened!!");
        }
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(databasePath, database);
    }
}
```

**So my question is:**
Can I (and how) insert to application's database (created by Java api) from NDK?

As workaround I guess would be possible to create temporary database (not encrypted), but I rather use the one I created beforehand by **Java's SQLiteOpenHelper**.

Comment: Start simply by extracting the file to your PC. If you can open it with sqlite there, you will be able to use http://blog.kdehairy.com/using-sqlite-natively-on-android/. If the file is encrypted, or damaged, you have a problem.

Comment: I pulled it and it's perfectly readable and writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem.
First let me say sorry because the problem is not visible from original code in my question.

I passed to C++ function path to database file returned by

```
getDatabasePath("database_name").getAbsolutePath()
```

but it seems that it returns path with symbolic links and that SQLite somehow cannot handle.

**Solution:**

```
try {
    getDatabasePath("database_name").getCanonicalPath();
}
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

*According to manual canonical does resolve symbolic links.*